# I want to add symbol at random place in string how can i do that?

Tags: php, arrays, string, trim

```
$string = "this is a string biggest string bigger than the string1 string";   
$random_position = rand(0, strlen($string) - 1);
$chars = "‍‍‍♀️‍♂️✡️♈️️‍❤️‍‍❤️‍";
$random_char = $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
$newString = substr($string, 0, $random_position) . $random_char . substr($string, $random_position);
echo $newString;
```

this is my code and I want to add these symbols in my string at random places but I can't do it. does anyone can help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `$chars` string has multibyte characters, so when you address `$chars[$i]` for some `$i`, you'll just get one part of a multibyte character, not in full.

The solution is to use [`mb_`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions:

```
$chars = mb_str_split("‍‍‍♀️‍♂️✡️♈️️‍❤️‍‍❤️‍");
$random_char = $chars[rand(0, count($chars) - 1)];
```

With this it will work.

Comment: ya but it is added only 1 symbol i want a minimum 10 add-in string

Comment: That's not what your code was attempting to do. Anyway, with this answer, it should be easy to do it more than once, no? What is the problem?

Comment: Nothing more problem but if you can help it more in this than it should be good for me

Comment: To get you started - pick a number between <min> and <max> (where min is the lesser of [10] and [the string length], and max is not bigger than the length of the string), and then run this function that many times in a loop.

Comment: ok, I understand a little bit but if possible in code?? if any reference link available than please provide me